# Auto populate date-time from the selection of location in html field

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a two html fields, one is a location (country) drop down and the other field is a date-time drop down.
When a user selects a country from the location drop down I want the current date-time to be auto populated with respect to the country selected from the dropdown.

How can this be done?

HTML code:

```
<html>
<body>
    <form>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="location">Location :</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select name="Location">
                    <option value="INDIA">INDIA</option>
                    <option value="US">US</option>
                    <option value="JAPAN">JAPAN</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="date">Date & Time :</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="date">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: You can post the selected country to a php script using an Ajax request, process the result and then set the input value. You should also use some kind of id as the option values instead of the country name.

Comment: Many countries have more than one timezone, which one should be used? Setting the time for a particular timezone based on the host system's time using javascript is trivial.

Comment: Can you please show how can i do that...

Comment: [*Javascript: get time in timezone*](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+get+time+in+timezone).

Comment: You can look at the answer [*here*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35834769/is-gettimezoneoffset-stable-during-daylight-saving-transition/35835097#35835097). Steps: create a date with *new Date()*, adjust the UTCMinutes for the required offset (+east, -west), build a formatted string using UTC methods.

Comment: Server time here is PST based on that when a country from different time zone is selected how should i populate....

Answer (score 0):

Many countries have more than one timezone. In the below JavaScript code I have used two timezones. The first one is the current Indian timezone or system date and time, and the second one is the USA timezone. This might guide you to find a solution.

[image]

Comment: Please post your code directly to question, no need of adding extra URLs that can become invalid in future.